# How to lay my nav bar over image?

Tags: css

I am trying to lay my lay my nav bar (@media min width 50em) over my my mainimage.  I have tried using mainimage as a background url to my navbar but it I cannot adjust the height.  Is there a way to just push mainimage to the top of page and have my nav bar lay over the top of it?

Here is a link to my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/shannonhart82/93ekqmhq/1/

```
  <nav>
      <ul>

         <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
         <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
         <li><img class="logo" src="fjc.svg"></li>


         <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>




     <img class="mainimage" src="http://www.andypost.com/media/original/Andy- Post-Food-Photography-Waffle-with-Syrup.jpg" width="100%">


   nav li a {
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: #9CD5CF;
     top: 0;
     padding: 70px;
     width: 150px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #000;
   }
   #nav-icon3 {
     display: none;
   }
   nav {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
   }
   nav li {
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: none;
     color: black;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
   }
   nav ul {
     text-align-last: center;
   }
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image: img]

Answer (score 2):

You could something like this with rest of your styles

```
.nav{
z-index: 2;
}
img{
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating a div around the nav, and put this in css

**html**

```
<div class="divclass">
  <nav>
  <ul>

     <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
     <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
     <li><img class="logo" src="fjc.svg"></li>


     <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.divclass {
    height:200px;
    background-image: url("http://www.andypost.com/media/original/Andy- Post-Food-Photography-Waffle-with-Syrup.jpg");
}
```